# How to "undo-like" translation function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, events, undo

I'm looking for a way to undo-like function in jQuery.

Basically, I got button which toggles some text divisions into different language using jQuery `.text()` & `.html()` method.
Default language used in html is english. Goal language german for example.

So, I have this function which is called by onclick event: 
(actually, its much much longer).

```
function translateToMyLang() {
     $("heading").text("Meine heading"); // default: My Heading
     $("menu").text("Meine menu"); // default: My menu
...
}
```

How can I create event which undo everything from function about to its default (html) state, instead of doing... :

```
function translateBack() {
     $("heading").text("");
     $("menu").text(""); 
    }
```

Comment: you should indicate whether your selector are class or id

Comment: That really doesn't matter, selectors are ID's, classes and tags.

Comment: I am pretty much sure I know selectors, I am just trying to say that your code won't work because of an unknown selectors..Or did I just miss those kind of selectors *heading, menu*??

Comment: Uhm.. Selector $("menu") selects <menu> </menu> tags. The code works with tag selectors. I am not sure what are you trying to say.

Comment: I am not aware of the menu tag, but I think there is no heading tag.. therefore the menu selectors will work.

Comment: You can create your own tags, like <whatever_i_want></whatever_i_want> and jquery selector $("whatever_i_want") will select it.

Answer (score 0):

If you put all your form elements into a form you can call .reset() on the form

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp

Or use:
$('.parentSelector').children().not('.ignoreThisClass').text("")

Comment: How can I put them to "form"?

Comment: wrap them in a form tag:

<form>

</form>

Assuming you're accepting user input here?

Comment: Like every element? I actually have over 150 elements to be translated....

Comment: you could do $('.parentSelector').children().text("") then.

Where .parentSelector is the class of the element containing the 150 elements

Comment: if you need to do anything more complicated check this out: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: The children method is actually good idea, but it resets all text and I just want reset the ones which were translated. (Some .text()'s remain in default language (like numbers, date, time and similiar).

Comment: add a class for the things you don't translate then do: $('.parentSelector').children().not('.ignoreThisClass').text("")

Comment: Oh, it seems to be long night. I think that I use custom property lang="en" or something like this.

Comment: But wait, $(".object").text(""); actualy clears text inside not revert it.